# Calling AngularJS inside <script> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive:

```
function Recaptcha(RecaptchaService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/login/recaptcha.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.sendResp = function(response) {
                RecaptchaService.sendResponse(response);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

With the template login/recaptcha :

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        $scope.sendResp(response);
    };
</script>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY-KEY" data-callback="verifyCallback"></div>
```

So, I want to call `$scope.sendResp` inside my `<script>`. But I'm getting `$scope is not defined`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: add the `verifyCallback` to a controller and pass in the ref to `$scope` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881478/how-to-call-a-method-defined-in-an-angularjs-directive

Comment: doens't work, already tried that

Comment: you mean $scope.verifyCallback inside the directive, and call it inside data-callback, right? @Pogrindis

Comment: As far as I am aware you can't access $scope outside a module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.. 
(This works only when the captcha div is inside ng-app)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        var el = document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha'),
            $el = angular.element(el),
            $scope = $el.scope();

            $scope && $scope.sendResp(response);
    };
</script>
```