# When does Angulars link function run?

Tags: angularjs

From what I understand it only runs once before the page is rendered. But is there ever a case where it runs after the page has been rendered?

I tried testing a few things with this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pYjVNnyK1hMHOdjBIH1u?p=preview):

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('test', function($http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<input />',
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        var input = angular.element(el[0].children[0]);
        input.on('change', function() {
          console.log('change event');
          scope.$apply(function() {
            console.log('digest cycle');
          });
        });
        input.on('keyup', function() {
          console.log('keyup event');
          var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
          $http.get(root+'/users')
            .success(function() {
              console.log('http request successful');
            })
            .error(function() {
              console.log('http request error');
            });
        });
        console.log('link function run');
      }
    };
  });
```

1. Does typing in the input field cause the link function to run?
2. Do event listeners cause the link function to run?
3. Do http requests (made with `$http`?) cause the link function to run?
4. Do digest cycles cause the link function to run?

The answer to all of these questions seem to be "no".

Comment: "And it's the linking function that executes once for each instantiation of the template." - [Misko Hevery](https://youtu.be/WqmeI5fZcho?t=16m41s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `link` function runs when an instance of the directive is compiled, in this case, when a `<test></test>` element is created. That can be when angular's bootstrapping compiles the page, when it comes into being from a `ng-if`, when a `ng-repeat` makes it, when it's made with `$compile`, etc.

`link` will never fire twice for the same instance of the directive. Notably, it fires right after the template has been compiled in the directive's lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you. I made this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0DT235h0Fd1VZLxpvKZC?p=preview) to demonstrate the `ng-repeat` scenario.

Comment: No problem. Is there anything that you want me to look at in the plnkr, or is that just for edification?

Comment: Not particularly, just thought it might be useful ad a demo.

Answer (score 2):

1 - No, it causes to change the only ng-model if you have it binded.

2 - No, it will only launch the code inside the event binds.

3 - Again no, the event bind will launch the `$http.get()`. And please don't put an $http directly on your directive. Use a `factory` or something like that.

4 - Dunno

As Dylan Watt said, the directive `link` runs only when the directive is compiled (only once) per element/attr.... You can compile it in different ways. Plain http, `$compile`, `ng-repeat`....

You can create a $watch inside your directive to "relaunch" some code on a binded element change.

This maybe can help you: [How to call a method defined in an AngularJS directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881478/how-to-call-a-method-defined-in-an-angularjs-directive)