# Update parent controller value from child angular function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to change a scope value in a parent controller from a child directive.

I've added `=` for two-way binding such that when I click on a the directive's `<tr>`, it will fire `openDetail`, which will update `scope.page`, which has been two-way bound.

Yet it's not updating the controller's `page` value.

Controller HTML:

```
TEST : {{page}} //Not changed

<questions-list></questions-list>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.page = 'Not changed';
```

Directive HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="q in questions" ng-click="openDetail( q.id )">
```

"Questions List" Directive:

```
scope: {
    page : '='
},
...

scope.openDetail = function (id) {
    scope.page = 'question_detail';
};
```

---

In [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881478/how-to-call-a-method-defined-in-an-angularjs-directive), the `ng-click` handlers are always bound on the Controller. In my case, I need to fire an event from the directive, change  directive value, and have it update the controller.

Comment: at child controller add `scope: true;`

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the parent scope's property to bind to via directive's element attribute:

```
<questions-list page="page"></questions-list>
```

Here the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bqfh6ggd/1).

Comment: Wait why do u need to call the attribute AND the value both page?

Comment: attribute is the name of scope property defined in directive. value is the scope property defined in controller that you need to pass to directive for two way binding.

Comment: The attribute name is the property name of  the directive's scope, the value is the property of the parent scope to bind to.

Comment: @Growler, as to "why" - as a directive's user you choose which properties of your parent scope to pass to it. It's not up to directive to choose. Kind of "modular" approach.

Answer (score 0):

I see a mistacke on your html :

```
<tr ng-repeat="q in questions ng-click="openDetail( q.id )">
```

must be replace by

```
<tr ng-repeat="q in questions" ng-click="openDetail( q.id )">
```

It missing a quote.

And for the problem, you use a primitive type to bind on directve. Try to encapsulate the value into an object on your parent scope :

```
$scope.page = { value: 'Not changed' };
<questions page="page.value">...</questions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some different methods doing this .

Once  consider your must pass values  from controller  to directive

like

```
scope: {
    page : '='
},
```

then

You  can't access parent scope so need to transclude your child scope hence but it seems  deprecated in some versions.

hence best practice is to  share page variable with $rootScope.page
first inject      $rootScope in both controller and directive Injections
and use

```
{{$root.page}}  // in controller
```

//and in directive function make this change

```
scope.openDetail = function (id) {
    $rootScope.page = 'question_detail';
};
```

Also if you need other ways like  #BROADCAST  or #EMIT  ( really great thing in angularjs)

///  in  directive

```
 $rootScope.$emit("emitName", {page:"page value" });
```

// in controller

```
 $rootScope.$on("emitName",function(event,data){
       $scope.page = data.page; // this comes from directive and assign to current scope's page variable 
   });
```

Please let me know if anyone works for you otherwise we can research more.

## khajaamin

Answer (score -1):

I created a sample App for you

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('testCon', function($scope) {

  $scope.page = "Parent controll";

});

app.directive('questions', function() {

  return {
    scope: true,
    controller: ['$scope',
      function($scope) {

      }
    ]
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCon">
  {{page}}

  <questions>{{page}}</questions>

</div>
```