# Angular: Can't use value of ng-repeat in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I want to have a div show up when clicked on the title, to do this i wanted to pass the value of the ng-repeat in the ng-click. But for some reason it doesn't get it through.

Here's the code of my list:

```
    <ul id="vak_lijst">

      <li ng-repeat="x in vakken.vakken | unique:'vaknaam'" ng-click="vakken.setSelected(x.vaknaam)">

        <span>{{ x.vaknaam }}</span>

        <div ng-show="vakken.selected = x.vaknaam">

            // some content

        </div>

      </li>

    </ul>
```

Here's my script:

```
            vakken.setSelected = function(vaknaam) {
                    vakken.selected = vaknaam;
                    console.log('clicked');
                  }
```

Excuse me that some names are in dutch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `{{` or `}}` to access variables inside the ng-click:

```
... ng-click="myControllerMethod(x.vaknaam)">Ga verder</button>
```

Comment: i didnt use {{ or }} but it still doesnt pass the value.

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(vaknaam)`? undefined?

Comment: I recommend creating a [mcve]. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881478/how-to-call-a-method-defined-in-an-angularjs-directive) may also give you some direction.

Comment: it gives the right name when i do console.log(vaknaam) but it still doesn't show the div

Comment: `vakken.selected == x.vaknaam`? You're setting when you use one equal sign.

Comment: wow, yeah that's it! thank you very much!! been lookin at this for quite a while can't believe i didn't notice that

Comment: Don't feel bad. It took me 6 hours one day to figure out a `;` (semi-colon) was in the correct place.