# Angular directive calling another directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hCLhRbpM4IZqdlrbYP1V?p=preview) I have directive `dir1` calling a method in directive `dir2` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881478/how-to-call-a-method-defined-in-an-angularjs-directive).

The problem is that the control object (`scope.dir2Ctl`) is empty in `dir1` and I get `TypeError: scope.dir2Ctl.call2 is not a function`. Any ideas how to fix this?

HTML

```
  <body ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="ctl">
    <dir1 x1="1"></dir1>
  </body>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module("myModule", [])
.controller('ctl', function($scope) {})

.directive('dir1', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',          
        scope: {
            x1: '='         
        },
        template: '<p>x2 should be 2 = {{x2}} </p>' + 
             '<dir2 control="dir2Ctl"></dir2>',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
              scope.dir2Ctl = {};
              $timeout(function(){
                  console.log(scope.dir2Ctl)
                  scope.x2 = scope.dir2Ctl.call2();
              },1000);
        }
    }
})

.directive('dir2', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',          
        scope: {
            control: '='         
        },
        template: '<p>some text in dir2</p>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
              scope.control = scope.control || {};
              scope.control.call2 = function(){
                 return 2;
              };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do here;  However, of course `control` would be an empty object;  You set `control="dir2Ctl"`, set `scope.dir2Ctl = {}` in the `link`, and then never set it to anything else.

Comment: I need to call method `call2` in `dir1`. Since I declared `control="dir2Ctl"` I am linking `scope.control` in `dir2` with `scope.dir2Ctl` in `dir1`, they are the same object.

Comment: but they aren't, because you re-initialized it to `{}` in the link.  remove that first line in the link, and this will work.

Comment: better do like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/ERIquSWHRPrGMdDZPOGs?p=preview

Comment: @Claies it worked

Comment: it worked in angular 1.2 - now you try angular 1.6

Comment: @Claies In this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KULuwD4gSn0HKFws9bak?p=preview) I am using `pre-link` to initialize `scope.dir2Ctl`, if I remove it as you suggested it works however the object is not initialized, I don't understand how `dir2` can declare the `call2` function if it's not initialized.

Comment: I think you are confused about the order of the postlink processing.  In the first example, where both are using postlink, the inner directive is linked first, and `scope.control` is "initialized" in the `scope.control = scope.control || {};` line, then passed passed out by the two way binding.  the outer directive is then linked, and `scope.dir2Ctl = {};` *overwrites* the object already initialized.  the object never really needed to be initialized in the outer directive at all.

Comment: in the second version, where the outer directive is using prelink, the situation is slightly different.  First, the `pre` is run, and `scope.dir2Ctl = {};` is set, then passed in to the inner directive through two way binding.  In the inner post link, `scope.control = scope.control || {};` doesn't re-initialize it because of the or clause.