# TypeError: $scope.resetDropzone is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropzone.js

I want to reset my dropZone area by clicking reset button but I can not call resetDropzone function(in directivejs) from my controller. Can you help me please My directive.js is:

```
function dropZone() {
console.log("access");
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var config = {
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/upload',
            maxFilesize: 100,
            paramName: "uploadfile",
            maxThumbnailFilesize: 10,
            parallelUploads: 1,
            autoProcessQueue: false
        };

        var eventHandlers = {
            'addedfile': function (file) {

                scope.file = file;
                if (this.files[1] != null) {
                    this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
                }
                scope.$apply(function () {

                    scope.fileAdded = true;
                });
            },

            'success': function (file, response) {
            }

        };

        dropzone = new Dropzone(element[0], config);

        angular.forEach(eventHandlers, function (handler, event) {
            dropzone.on(event, handler);
        });

        scope.processDropzone = function () {
            dropzone.processQueue();
        };

        scope.resetDropzone = function () {
            console.log("resetDropzon mthd");
            dropzone.removeAllFiles();
        };
    }
}
```

}

I call this function from html code as ng-click="reset()" and my controller is:

```
$scope.reset = function () {
    console.log("reset mthd");
    $scope.resetDropzone();
};
```

Comment: where `$scope.reset` function resides? it doesn't seems to be part of directive shared scope..

Comment: `$scope.reset` reside in my controller (MainCtrl.js). How can I fix it? Is there anything that I should change it?

Answer (score 1):

resetDropzone() resides in the isolated scope of your directive. You can't call it from your controller scope.

Here you can find an example how to achieve your scenario.
[How to call a method defined in an AngularJS directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881478/how-to-call-a-method-defined-in-an-angularjs-directive)

Bind your directive to an object in your controller scope and define resetDropzone method to this object. You will be able to call it from the controller.