# angular - call directive function from html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to call a function in a directive from a template of other directive

discount.directive

```
angular.module('main').directive('dtDiscount', function(discountFactory, languageFactory, $ionicPopup) {
return {
    scope: {
        operators: '=operators',

        toggle: '=toggle',
    },
    templateUrl: 'templates/components/discount.html',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

   $scope.setDiscount = function(value, fromDrag){
     ....
   }
 }

 ....
```

discount html

```
<div class="drag-input-horizontial" dt-drag-horizontial ng-model="s3">
```

drag.horizontial.directive

```
angular.module('main').directive('dtDragHorizontial', function($window, 
$ionicScrollDelegate) {
return {
require: 'ngModel',
scope: {

},
templateUrl: 'templates/components/horizontial-drag-input.html',
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {

}
```

horizontial.drag-input.html

I want to call setDiscount function in discount.directive.Does anyone know how I can do this?

```
<ds> 
<da ng-click="setDiscount(3,true)">someText</da>
</ds>
```

Comment: remove `scope ` from dtDragHorizontial and check as its isolated scope will not take parents methods

Comment: You can read this 
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881478/how-to-call-a-method-defined-in-an-angularjs-directive)