# call a directive function from controller without isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolated-scope

Is there a way of calling a function defined in a directive from the parent controller without using isolated scope or events?

Comment: can you give an example as to what you want to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a method defined in an AngularJS directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881478/how-to-call-a-method-defined-in-an-angularjs-directive)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey The accepted answer in the proposed duplicate uses isolate scope. The OP specifically asks for an answer that avoids isolate scope.

Comment: If you don't mind cluttering the AngularJS event bus with events, you can use `$scope.$root.$broadcast` and `scope.$on`. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Events Propagation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation).