# AngularJS - Call specific Directive function/method from Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Directive**

```
 myApp.directive('vlcControls', function ($compile, $rootScope, $timeout, $window, pictureboxConstants) {


    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {


    vlcPlayerCustomTemplate = 'some html goes here';


                scope.getVLC = function (name) {
                    if ($window.document[name]) {
                        return $window.document[name];
                    }
                    if ($window.navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet") == -1) {
                        if ($window.document.embeds && $window.document.embeds[name])
                            return $window.document.embeds[name];
                    } else {
                        return $window.document.getElementById(name);
                    }
                }

                scope.doPlayPause = function (vlcPlayer, event) {
                    var vlc = scope.getVLC(vlcPlayer);
                    if (vlc) {

                        if (vlc.playlist.isPlaying) {
                            vlc.playlist.pause();
                            angular.element(event.target).children().removeClass('fa fa-pause font-12');
                            angular.element(event.target).children().addClass('fa fa-play font-12');

                        } else {
                            if (vlc.audio.mute == true) {
                                //do something
                            }
                            vlc.playlist.play();
                        }
                    }
                }

            angular.element(document.querySelector("#controls" + index)).append(element.html(vlcPlayerCustomTemplate));
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    };
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: linker
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
myModule.controller('myModuleCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $controller, $compile) {

$compile("<vlc-controls></vlc-controls>")($rootScope);

});
```

What is the best way to only call specific `directive` function/method `doPlayPause` from `controller` without using `vlcPlayerCustomTemplate` html elements or any `DOM` manipulations ?

Comment: Just I was wondering, do you have a chance to look at my answer below which works nicely with `$compile` as you expected without the `DOM` manipulations?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$broadcast` and `$on` to handle the communication from controller to directive.

To me, this is a code smell. If something is shared between parent and directive scope, it should be done through a binding. If you have to use the pub-sub pattern like this, you should rethink how you're using your directives, IMO.

Your directive should be able to do whatever it needs to without being called directly from the parent controller. If there's something it needs from the parent controller, it should be bound using attributes or a non-isolate scope.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to `$broadcast` an event from the `controller` to `directive` and to listen in directive.

You can even send the parameters in the form of an object through it.

`$rootScope.$broadcast('PlayPause',{});` will be in controller

in directive,

```
scope.$on('PlayPause',function(event, data){
      scope.doPlayPause(data.vlcPlayer, data.event)
});
```

**Controller:**

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($rootScope){
  var that = this;

  this.select = function(){
      $rootScope.$broadcast('PlayPause',{vlcPlayer: 'vlcPlayer',event: 'event'});
  }
})
```

**Directive:**

```
myApp.directive('vlcControls', function ($compile, $rootScope, $timeout, $window, pictureboxConstants) {


    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {


                scope.getVLC = function (name) {
                    if ($window.document[name]) {
                        return $window.document[name];
                    }
                    if ($window.navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet") == -1) {
                        if ($window.document.embeds && $window.document.embeds[name])
                            return $window.document.embeds[name];
                    } else {
                        return $window.document.getElementById(name);
                    }
                }

                scope.doPlayPause = function (vlcPlayer, event) {
                    var vlc = scope.getVLC(vlcPlayer);
                    if (vlc) {

                        if (vlc.playlist.isPlaying) {
                            vlc.playlist.pause();
                            angular.element(event.target).children().removeClass('fa fa-pause font-12');
                            angular.element(event.target).children().addClass('fa fa-play font-12');

                        } else {
                            if (vlc.audio.mute == true) {
                                //do something
                            }
                            vlc.playlist.play();
                        }
                    }
                }

                 scope.$on('PlayPause',function(event, data){
                    scope.doPlayPause(data.vlcPlayer, data.event)
                });
    };
    return {
myApp.directive('vlcControls', function ($compile, $rootScope, $timeout, $window, pictureboxConstants) {


    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {


                scope.getVLC = function (name) {
                    if ($window.document[name]) {
                        return $window.document[name];
                    }
                    if ($window.navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet") == -1) {
                        if ($window.document.embeds && $window.document.embeds[name])
                            return $window.document.embeds[name];
                    } else {
                        return $window.document.getElementById(name);
                    }
                }

                scope.doPlayPause = function (vlcPlayer, event) {
                    var vlc = scope.getVLC(vlcPlayer);
                    if (vlc) {

                        if (vlc.playlist.isPlaying) {
                            vlc.playlist.pause();
                            angular.element(event.target).children().removeClass('fa fa-pause font-12');
                            angular.element(event.target).children().addClass('fa fa-play font-12');

                        } else {
                            if (vlc.audio.mute == true) {
                                //do something
                            }
                            vlc.playlist.play();
                        }
                    }
                }

                 scope.$on('PlayPause',function(event, data){
                    scope.doPlayPause(data.vlcPlayer, data.event)
                });
    };
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: linker
    };
});
```

The other way is to use a factory and share the method between the `controller` and `directive`,

[Check this so post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883476/call-method-in-directive-controller-from-other-controller/14884646#14884646)

Comment: The directive when called from a controller, sets some DOM elements dynamically. The question here is how to call specific method from that directive assuming we do not want the DOM manipulation but only the functions.

Comment: since,`doPlayPause` is a function in the directive,   `scope.doPlayPause(data.vlcPlayer, data.event)` just calls that function, 
`scope.doPlayPause()` without the parameters.

Comment: Updated the directive where I added `vlcPlayerCustomTemplate`. I do not want that HTML but only want to call a function from that directive ? If I call the directive, it will also append HTML which I do not want but to call a function only.

Comment: If you just want to call a function, why cant you move it to a service or factory, directives are mainly intended to manipulate the dom, and if there is a directive in a HTML, it will definitely gets executed. The answer I have given can call a method in directive from a controller, have you checked that the DOM has changed?

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways to do that, one of them is through broadcasting an event and listening to it in directive

However, I am not aware of the entire context and what exactly are you trying to achieve, but it looks like there is a small issue in a design. The question I would ask is "why would you want to call a method in a directive from parent controller?" Ideally, when you work with directive, it's functionality is self-contained and if you need to interact with outside world, then you either do it through variables binding or, as I already mentioned, events.

I am sure that there is a way to do exactly what you want, but given the information in the post, it is not necessary.

Comment: Assume that  the directive `<vlc-controls>` sets DOM elements alogn with some functions which can be reused. How can we call that functions defined in a directive from a controller ?

Comment: Again, similar to what @Yatrix mentioned, it looks like a code smell. You should look at this whole structure as separate modules, while each module has its own elements. Now, actions on these elements, do something within the module. And when that something happens, you can broadcast an event which will be listened by anyone who is interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to call the `directive` methods from the `controller` without any `DOM` manipulation and you can achieve the same with help of `isolated scope` as below.

You can have an `isolated scope` in your `directive` as below.

```
scope: {
           /* This is the reference object passed from the controller */
           controllerRef: '='
       }
```

Then you can pass the same from the `controller`,

```
$scope.vlcControls = {};

$compile('<vlc-controls controller-ref="vlcControls"></vlc-controls>')($scope);
```

Then you can assign the methods to this object in the directive,

```
      scope.controllerRef = scope.controllerRef || {};

      angular.extend(scope.controllerRef, {
         doPlayPause: scope.doPlayPause,
         // This is just for an example
         callDirectiveFromController: scope.callDirectiveFromController
      });
```

And you are now pretty much ready to call any of these methods from the controller as below,

```
$scope.vlcControls.callDirectiveFromController();
```

Check the code below and execute which is working nicely as you expected :-)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myModuleCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $controller, $compile) {
   $scope.vlcControls = {};
  
   $compile('<vlc-controls controller-ref="vlcControls"></vlc-controls>')($scope);
  
   $scope.vlcControls.callDirectiveFromController();

});

myApp.directive('vlcControls', function ($compile, $rootScope, $timeout, $window)//, pictureboxConstants) 
            {


    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {


                scope.getVLC = function (name) {
                    if ($window.document[name]) {
                        return $window.document[name];
                    }
                    if ($window.navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet") == -1) {
                        if ($window.document.embeds && $window.document.embeds[name])
                            return $window.document.embeds[name];
                    } else {
                        return $window.document.getElementById(name);
                    }
                };

                scope.doPlayPause = function (vlcPlayer, event) {
                    var vlc = scope.getVLC(vlcPlayer);
                    if (vlc) {

                        if (vlc.playlist.isPlaying) {
                            vlc.playlist.pause();
                            angular.element(event.target).children().removeClass('fa fa-pause font-12');
                            angular.element(event.target).children().addClass('fa fa-play font-12');

                        } else {
                            if (vlc.audio.mute == true) {
                                //do something
                            }
                            vlc.playlist.play();
                        }
                    }
                };
      
           scope.callDirectiveFromController = function() {
              console.log('I called from the controller but executed inside the directive :-)');
           };
   
          scope.controllerRef = scope.controllerRef || {};

          angular.extend(scope.controllerRef, {
             doPlayPause: scope.doPlayPause,
             // This is just for an example
             callDirectiveFromController: scope.callDirectiveFromController
          });
    };
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
          /* This is the reference object passed from the controller */
          controllerRef: '='
        },
        link: linker
    };
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myModuleCtrl">
</div>
```